# Keystonejs: change admin UI login screen message

Tags: javascript, node.js, keystonejs

**Keystonejs** has some kind of bug on the Admin UI login page:

While trying to access Keystone Admin UI, with `User` that Permissions `isAdmin = false`

In case login/pass is correct Keystonejs screen says: `"You're already signed in."`

There should be response something like: "You don't have permissions"

It's no too informative so I suggest to change it to something like `"You don't have permissions".`

So question: is it possible to change text of that message?

Comment: What specific version of Keystone are you using? I can't reproduce this issue with Keystone 4.0.0; the message is "The email and password you entered are not valid". Can you provide the exact steps to reproduce the issue?

Comment: @Stennie Keystone version: 4.0.0. To reproduce that:
create one more User and set Permissions isAdmin = false. Then try to login with that user to Admin UI. Message will be: "You're already signed in."

Comment: I didn't quite correctly describe the question. Updated it.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you have logged in using valid credentials but have not granted that user access to the Admin UI. There is (as at Keystone 4.0.0) no default path for users without the `canAccessKeystone` permission. I believe the general assumption was that non-admin users should not be logging into Keystone admin, but authenticated sessions are still useful for API endpoints.

> So question: is it possible to change text of that message?

I'm not aware of a straightforward way to only change this message, but if you're keen you could always modify the Keystone 4.0 source for your own requirements and [submit a pull request](https://help.github.com/articles/creating-a-pull-request/) to have this considered for merging into the project. I've created [issue #4786](https://github.com/keystonejs/keystone/issues/4786) in Keystone's GitHub issue tracker to improve the messaging for users who successfully login but do not have access to the admin UI.

In the interim, one possible workaround would be to use the keystone `signin redirect` configuration to set a preferred entry point that can either handle all user types or redirect appropriately.

For example, you could add the following to your `keystone.js` config:

```
keystone.set('signin redirect', '/gohome')
```

The `/gohome` route could render a page or do a simple redirection based on user properties:

```
app.get('/gohome', function(req, res) {
    var url = (req.user && req.user.canAccessKeystone) ? '/keystone' : '/user';
    res.redirect(url);
});
```